# Why is the program keep on asking for the input in C?

Tags: c

I am able to run the program but its not doing what it is supposed to . It keeps on asking for the number. ( WRITTEN IN C )

Algorithm I am trying to follow is -
Step 1: Set the value of guess to 1.
Step 2: If |guess^2 - x| < ε, proceed to step 4. (ε= epsilon)
Step 3: Set the value of guess to (x / guess + guess) / 2 and return to step 2.
Step 4: The guess is the approximation of the square root.

[This is the output I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d4CsI.png)

```
#include <stdio.h>

float sqr_root(float n);
float absolute_value(float n) ;

int main(void)
{
    float n ;
    printf("Enter a positive number :");
    scanf("%f" , &n);

    printf("Square root of %f is %f \n" , n , sqr_root(n) );

}


float absolute_value(float n)
{
    if (n < 0)
    {
        n = -n ;
    }
    return (n) ;
}

float sqr_root(float n)
{
    const float epsilon = 0.00001 ;
    float guess = 1.0 ;

    float value = absolute_value( (guess * guess ) - n ) ;

    while (value > epsilon )
    {
        guess = (( n / guess) + guess ) / 2 ;
    }


    return guess ;
}
```

Comment: Show us what you are seeing.

Comment: `while (value > epsilon )` loop never enters/ends because `value, epsilon` do not change value.. Maybe recalculate `value = asolute_value( (guess * guess ) - n ) ;` in loop?

Comment: This is the output http://i.stack.imgur.com/d4CsI.png

Comment: Why are you squaring `1.0` etc as the first guess anyway? `1.0 * 1.0 = 1.0`. With this algorithm, the first guess for square root can be `n` or `n / 2`. Even better, dump `float` and use `double` unless you have a very good reason not to.

Comment: Thank you ! After inserting value in loop its working now .Thanks

Comment: Weather vane  which float should I change to double ?

Comment: Why my question is getting bad responses ?

Comment: I recommend all of them. `float` is for 1980 tutorials or for restrictive libraries or tiny MPUs. You don't code integers with `short` do you?

Comment: Why my question is getting bad responses ?

Comment: I did not downvote however you did not post the text of the output in the original question.

Comment: You have 2 "don't like" for unspecified reasons (quite typical) and one * for "favorite Q" and one helpful answer we like. What's wrong then?

Comment: 1) Post the responses and other relevant data  here, rather than in a linked location.  2) The inconsistent spelling of code of "absolute"  indicated the post was not a true copy.  3) With small corrections, entering 4 resulted in an infinite loop for me, not the 8 posted.  These and others like lead to the DVs.

Comment: .. apart from the question "Why is the program keep on asking for the input in C?" when there is no evidence of that happening. There is one input in `main` and it is not repeated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`while (value > epsilon )` loop never enters/ends because `value, epsilon` do not change value.

Add `value = asolute_value( (guess * guess ) - n ) ;` to loop with the corrected spelling.

```
while (value > epsilon )
{
    guess = (( n / guess) + guess ) / 2 ;
    value = absolute_value((guess * guess ) - n ) ;
}
```